# Mapping nested raw List with MapStruct

Tags: java, json, jersey, dto, mapstruct

I am trying to map my legacy API object (I can not change it), which has nested raw `List` type property. The elements of the list are not compatible with elements of DTO list and should be mapped explicitly as nested. Unfortunately it looks like MapStruct considers raw `List` as compatible with all typed lists and ignores any mapping, which I try to specify and the generated code does not work correctly producing error later, somewhere in serializer.

My API object has nested raw type list:

```
@Getter
public class ApiObject {
    protected Long uid;
    protected String name;
    List values; // Raw type list. Elements not compatible with DTO Value type.
}
```

My DTO object has generic typed list of DTO Value type elements:

```
@Setter
public class DtoObject {
    protected Long uid;
    protected String name;
    List <Value> values; // Should be mapped with ApiObject.values
}
```

In the mapper abstract class I am trying to specify custom mapper, which understands how to map API values to DTO values:

```
@Mapping(target = "values", source = "values", qualifiedByName = "myCustomValueMapper")
public abstract DtoObject map(final ApiObject apiObject);
```

... but MapStruct still ignores myCustomValueMapper and the produced mapper impl object looks like below (note that incompatible API value objects assigned to DTO value objects):

```
@Override
public DtoObject map(APiObject apiObject) {
    if ( apiObject == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    DtoObject dtoObject = new DtoObject();

    List list = apiObject.getValues();
    if ( list != null ) {
        dtoObject.setValues( new ArrayList<Value>( list ) );  // This code produces error later, in serializer.
    }
    else {
        dtoObject.setValues( null );
    }
    dtoObject.setUid( apiObject.getUid() );
    dtoObject.setName( apiObject.getName() );

    return dtoObject;
}
```

Is there any possibility in MapStruct to specify mapping for elements of nested raw List, or may be any workaround to achieve compatible mapping?

Comment: How does the myCustomValueMapper look like?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a default method to explicitly manage the conversion of the items in the list:

```
@Mapper
public interface ApiMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "values", source = "values")
    DtoObject map(final ApiObject apiObject);

    default List<Value> mapToValueList(List list) {
        List<Value> values = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Object o: list) {
            Value value = new Value();
            // here goes code to convert o -> Value
            // ...
            values.add(value);
        }
        return values;
    }
}
```

The generated code looks like this:

```
public class ApiMapperImpl implements ApiMapper {

    @Override
    public DtoObject map(ApiObject apiObject) {
        if ( apiObject == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        DtoObject dtoObject = new DtoObject();
        if ( dtoObject.getValues() != null ) {
            List<Value> list = mapToValueList( apiObject.getValues() );
            if ( list != null ) {
                dtoObject.getValues().addAll( list );
            }
        }
        return dtoObject;
    }
}
```

`List<Value> list = mapToValueList( apiObject.getValues() );` will call the default method on the interface (note that ApiMapperImpl implements the ApiMapper interface).

Comment: This solved the problem and I do not have the error in serializer anymore, thanks! My mapper is abstract class, not interface, so I just added non-abstract method similar to Bart's default method. As I have dedicated mapping of API value to DTO Value in the same mapper class, I am using short `values.add(map(o));`, which is making manually written code of mapToValueList equal to MapStruct autogenerated code for nested typed lists (when raw `List` not used). The question is, how to tell MapStruct to apply my dedicated mapping of API value to DTO Value automatically?

Comment: Your question would be easier to understand with some concrete code, but if I interpret it correctly: once you override mapstruct's autogenerated code (as mapToValueList does), then you're on your own. Again, if I understand correctly, you've defined a mapper from Object to Value, let's say you've called it 'mapToValue'; you can simply call it from within mapToValueList: replace the body of the for with ```values.add(mapToValue(o));```

Comment: Thank you. I have the code as you wrote, which works correctly: `for (Object o : list)  {values.add(mapToValue(o));}` Next, am looking at the code, which MapStruct generates for the mapping of the typed list, like `List<Value> mapApiValueListToDtoValueList(List<ApiValue> list);`. For this typed list mapping MapsStruct produces the code, which is very similar to what we have coded manually. I am looking is it possible to have MapStruct to autogenerate the code in my case too, when source list is not typed, but raw `List`.

Comment: It looks like adding typed list mapper like `List<Value> mapApiValueListToDtoValueList(List<ApiValue> list);` which I mentioned earlier, does solve the problem and MapStruct starts to automatically generate necessary code for me calling `values.add(mapToValue(o));` automatically as needed.

Comment: In your question you didn't mention ApiValue; there ApiObject.Values is an untyped List. Happy you've solved your problem, but the it seems to be different from the one you posted :)